# Add user to group in signal post_save

Tags: django, authentication, signals, user-permissions, createuser

I want to add a user to a group after the user object is saved. Each user has a user type corresponding to the group the user belongs to. For example, if the user_type is 2, then the user belongs to Group_3, and so on.
This is my code:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """ Custom user model """
    USER_TYPE = ((1, 'HOD'), (2, 'Staff'), (3, 'Student'))
    email = models.EmailField(
        _("Email Address"),
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        help_text="Ex: example@example.com",
    )
    eec = models.ForeignKey(
        EEC, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='eec',blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_("Staff status"), default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_("Active"), default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_("Date Joined"), auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(_("Last Updated"), auto_now=True)
    user_type = models.IntegerField(default=1, choices=USER_TYPE)
    lastName = models.CharField(default='', max_length=250)
    firstName = models.CharField(default='', max_length=250)
    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class Teacher(models.Model):
    admin = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.user_type == 1:
            Admin.objects.create(admin=instance)
        if instance.user_type == 2:
            try:

                Teacher.objects.create(admin=instance)
                g1 = Group.objects.get(name='teacher')
                instance.groups.add(g1)


            except:
                print("Exception")
        if instance.user_type == 3:
            Student.objects.create(admin=instance)



Basically, when I save the user model with a user type of 2, the group does not get updated
```